# set maximum window size

Tags: common-lisp, tk-toolkit, ltk

How can I set the maximum window size of a LTK window?

```
(ql:quickload "ltk")

(defpackage :pub-quiz
  (:use :ltk :cl))

(in-package :pub-quiz)

(defun pub-quiz-window ()
  (with-ltk ()
    (let* ((f (make-instance 'frame :relief :groove :height 500 :width 300))
           (pub (make-instance 'label :master f :text "Pub Quiz"))
           (outtext (make-instance 'text :font "monospaced" :wrap :word))
           (tf (make-instance 'text  :font "monospaced")))
      (pack f)
      (pack pub :side :left)
      (pack outtext :ipady 100)
      (pack tf))))
```

If I set the frame size to height and width like in the above code sample, my window wm does not respect these values at all.

The Tk docs have this

```
wm maxsize .window 500 500
```

but I don't know how to translate this into something LTK understands.

Comment: I took the liberty of formatting your code, since it was hard to tell where the variables of the `let` ended and where the body began.  Can you post the additional code that someone would need in order to test this?  E.g., definitions of `*questions*` and `format-quiz`.  Also, a note that this definition needs to be in a context where the package `LTK` is used (e.g., `with-ltk`, `pack`, `frame`, `label`, etc., are all in the `LTK` package.

Comment: Thanks, I added the package definition.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used LTK, so I can't make much claim about how this is *supposed* to be done;  I'm just answering based on what I've found online. The [LTK manual](http://www.peter-herth.de/ltk/ltkdoc.pdf) mentions in section 3.7 that there is a `maxsize` function:

> ```
> (maxsize toplevel width height)
> ```
>
> Set the maximum size of the window in pixels.

Calling `(maxsize f 500 500)` doesn't work though.  The implementation of `maxsize` is:

```
(defgeneric maxsize (widget x y))
(defmethod maxsize ((w widget) x y)
  (format-wish "wm maxsize ~a ~a ~a" (widget-path w) (tk-number x) (tk-number y))
  w)
```

The number translation works just fine, I think `(ltk::tk-number 500) => 500`.  However, `(widget-path f)`, for the `f` in your code returns `.wc`, not `.window`, as the TK snippet you posted shows.  You could run that code directly with

```
(format-wish "wm maxsize .window 500 500")
```

but that causes an error too:

```
Tcl/Tk error: bad window path name ".window"
```

I'm not sure what element's path will work for you in this case, but it seems like once you've found that, `maxsize` will do what you need it to.  There is a `toplevel` class, and calling `maxsize` with instances of it seems to work, so perhaps you should explore

```
(let* ((f (make-instance 'toplevel :relief :groove :height 500 :width 300))
       ...)
  ...
  (maxsize f 500 500))
```

Playing around with it, I can *sort of* get that to work, although that "Pub Quiz" label seems to keep appearing as a separate window…

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your query correctly, but given the title I assume you want to ensure that the window opened must not be expanded beyond a given dimension?

If so, you have to set the master window `.` which is accessible via `*tk*`:

```
(defun pub-quiz-window ()
  (maxsize *tk* 300 300)
  (minsize *tk* 300 300)
  (let* ((f (make-instance 'frame :relief :groove :height 50 :width 30))
         (pub (make-instance 'label :master f :text "Pub Quiz"))
         (outtext (make-instance 'text :font "monospaced" :width 10 :height 10))
         (tf (make-instance 'text  :font "monospaced" :height 10 :width 10)))
    (pack f :side :left)
    (pack pub :side :left)
    (pack outtext :side :left)
    (pack tf :side :left)))

(defun create-local-view ()
  (with-ltk ()
    (pub-quiz-window)))
```